# cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy doesn't work in ng-template

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I have used `ng-template` with `cdk` to create a `overlay`. And I hope this cdk's position can be change automaticlly with the change of `cdkOverlayOrigin`.

So I use `cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy`, But it doesn't work, What should I do next?

```
HTML:

<div cdkOverlayOrigin>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
<ng-template
  cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="cdkOverlayOrigin"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="guideOpen"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayPositions]="position"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayScrollStrategy]="stratege">
  <div class="guide-container">
    <div class="guide-body-container">
      <div class="guide-arrow" [ngClass]="guidePlacement"></div>
      <div class="text-container">
        This is my<br/>
        guide
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

TS:

public stratege: ScrollStrategy = this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition();
```